# Android App with Multiple Activities - Same one always opens

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm messing around with the latest Android SDK (level 17), and I'm running into a very strange problem. I'm trying to make a custom Launcher, but in addition, my Application will contain a few other Activities that should be lauchable.

Here's the problem. I run the app using the simulator (using the latest ADT plugin and SDK tools), and everything looks like I expect. I see my 3 activities in the laucher (one for my custom launcher, and one each for the other two activities. Call them Activity A and Activity B).

1) I launch Activity A. Activity A opens. 
2) I hit the Home button. 
3) Now I launch Activity B. But Activity A opens again!

If I do this, it works:

1) I launch Activity A. Activity A opens.
2) I hit the BACK button.
3) Now I launch Activity B. Activity B opens as expected.

I'm fairly certain it has to be a problem with my Manifest file, but I don't see any obvious issues. Does anyone see something I'm doing wrong?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home"
    android:label="@string/home_title" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.home.Home"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.home.Wallpaper"
        android:icon="@drawable/bg_android_icon"
        android:label="Wallpaper" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.home.AppWhitelist"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app_whitelist" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.home.Paint"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_paint"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I think you should call finish() in onPause on Activity A. Pressing the back button finishes an activity, while pressing the home button calls onPause. It looks like the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: That may work - I'll give it a try later tonight, but I don't think I should *have* to call finish() in onPause, right?

Comment: Your app is  working fine according to the activity lifecycle. As @RaymondP said pressing home button doesn't closes the activity so you have to handle that yourself (In my another problem which bring me to this question it got solved by android:launchMode="singleTop" Just saying it might somebody)